# Let $x, y$ be integers. If we factor $x+y$ can we avoid factoring $x-y$?

Tags: prime-factorization

Let $x + y = a b$ be a factorization of $x + y$. Since $x - y = x + y - 2y$, we have $x - y = a b -  2y$. If $a | 2y$ then $x - y = a(b - z)$ for some integer $z$. Hence, in this case only $x+y$ needed to be factored to obtain the factorization of $x - y$. In what other cases can a factorization of $x+y$ be used to quickly obtain the factorization of $x-y$?

Comment: Just imagine the case of two huge numbers that differ by $1$ or two huge odd numbers that differ by $2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin the prime factorization of $x+y$ is completely independent of prime factorization of $x-y$ .Am I right?

Comment: I would say so, yes. I have no rigorous statement in mind that needs a proof, though. But certainly you know that factoring $x$ will never help you factor $x+1$ (or vice versa), so it's of the same nature.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for clarifications.

Comment: Do you mean the prime factorization of $\ x-y\ $ or just some (partial) factorization ?

Comment: I mean partial factorization